# WebBrowser rendering differences with accentuated texts

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, diacritics, html-rendering

I'm currently designing a C# under framework 4.0, using Visual Studio 15, where a WebBrowser object is used to display some information. 
When I load a file into the WebBrowser, using an URL like `C:\temp\myfile.html`, all is displayed perfectly.

When I'm using a string that contains exactly the same content than the file, every accentuated characters appears as a joker character (a diamond shape with a question mark...).

Please note, I'm using embedded CSS specifications in the two cases, but I'm pretty sure it has no consequences about my problem, as I tested with or without the CSS section, with exactly the same result.

The code used to set Html page from file is:

```
webMain.Navigate("about:blank");
while (webMain.Document == null || webMain.Document.Body == null) Application.DoEvents();
if (url != null) webMain.Navigate(url);
```

The code used to set Html page from string is:

```
webMain.DocumentText = "0";
webMain.Document.OpenNew(true);
webMain.Document.Write(_html);
webMain.Visible = true;
webMain.Refresh();`
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: You proberly need to set the correct encoding - something like webMain.Document.Encoding = "UTF-8" or whatever encoding applies to the data in your _html string

Comment: Certainly, however, there is such a setting in the beginning of the Html:  <html>
<head>
<title>Champollion 2019</title>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

Comment: Ok, I would expect the webbrowser control to respect that, but that is just guessing from my side. Are you sure the encodnig matches the content of the document? That the document is actually iso-8859-1 and not utf-8 or some other codepage

Comment: Pretty sure: it is displayed correctly when the file is loaded either in the WebBrowser object, or into actual browsers (Firefox, IE, Edge, Chrome...)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after a further struggle, it appeared that the issue was due to the way I was creating the Html string: it was stored as an embedded resource, and not properly decoded when invoked. 
Thanks to the ones that tried to help me, the issue was, as often, not coming from where I first thought.